# Boot Camp disappears (Big Sur)

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

After running Boot Camp Assistant on Big Sur and getting a message about successful merge of my Boot Camp partition, the free space was not added to the macOS partition and is not shown in the Disk Utility app.

After running `diskutil list` this is shown as "free space":

[image]

How can I merge this free space and my Big Sur partition without formatting everything, if possible?

Comment: The free space is after the BootCamp partition and you can't add it to Mac os x. Windows is it active on your Mac?

Comment: nope, 116gb free space is what left from bootcamp drive after using bootcamp assistant. 803 gb drive is another NTFS drive for filestorage.

Comment: So you deleted the BootCamp (Windows) partition. Unfortunately the NTFS partition placed between the Mac os x container and the free space, prevents this free space from being attached to the Mac os x container. Otherwise you have to save this NTFS partition, delete it and there you can add the desired space to the container and then recreate an NTFS partition to restore your data.

Comment: Is there proper software for macOS that can deal with it? I am pretty sure I can easily do it in Windows without erasing everything.

Comment: I don't know, bur before modify your Mac os x structure under Windows, I strongly advise you doing a Time Machine save or better a Carbon Copy Cloner clone before.

Comment: Thanks already did it through FreeFileSync. I do not have windows now for obvious reasons, so the only way I can do something is through macOS. p.s. Why Carbon Copy Cloner is better then Time Machine?

Comment: CCC create a clone on external or internal volume and you can boot from this. But CCC can only clone Mac ois x volumes, I don't think it can save a NTFS one. If your NTFS Volume can be saved on external disk (I suppose you have a Mac os X extension as Paragon NTFS) the better way is save this NTFS volume, then suppress it. After you add all space to Mac os X, then you resize the Mac os x container to create a new NTFS partition and you restore from the previous backup.

Comment: I always wondered how live sync software like Mega, Google etc will behave in moment of critical disk failure or volume erase like now. Will all the files in the cloud will be erased as well?

Comment: I don't know how to answer, but the solution may be to temporarily disconnect the Mac from the network during these operations.

Comment: Thanks for help. How to do partition correctly to avoid this in future? I am afraid after new re-partitioning I having "files" partition in between macos and windows partition again.

Comment: You want reinstall Windows by BootCamp? If yes, I'm not sure that Bootcamp will work on a disk with more than one Container/Partition. In this case, the solution would by suppress the Data partition, add all the space to your Container, then install Windows and after resize it to create the Data partition. But you will have the same problem. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I already re-installed windows. And, as I said earlier, "files" partition is in between macos and windows partition again. So the next time Windows breaks (should be excepted very soon) I will need to erase everything on my drive like is was this time. How to avoid erase in future?

Comment: The `diskutil list` given in your question is it updated?

Comment: The current one is here: https://dropmefiles.com.ua/en/MWhXR

Comment: I'm not sure you can reinstall Windows without wiping this data partition.
The solution might be to use Winclone  https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone/ to back up the Windows partition and restore it as needed.